# Facebook SDK API: How to get details on post shares?

Tags: facebook, api, sdk, facebook-fql

I'm using the FB PHP SDK to get info on a post in a page I manage.
So far I can get:

```
$result = $facebook->api("/123xx");
$result = $facebook->api("/123xx/likes");
$result = $facebook->api("/123xx/comments");
$result = $facebook->api("/123xx/insights");
```

This gives me a lot of info, but I'm missing details about 'shares'. All I get is

```
[shares] => Array
    (
        [count] => 13
    )
```

but no user ids or comments associated with those shares. Is there a way to pull that info with the SDK (or FQL)?

Regarding permissions, my script is asking for `'scope' => 'manage_pages,read_insights'` Do I need another param to request this info?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: I guess you'll have to content yourself with that.

Comment: In my (limited) experience with the FB API, this is the first piece of data that I find available through their own web front-end, but not through the API.